# IIS 6 compression configuration as told by Jeff

Tags: iis, configuration, compression

I've been reading up on the merits of IIS 6 compression over at CodingHorror ([here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html)), but I don't get where I'm supposed to make those alterations. Web.config or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the IIS configuration file Metabase.xml. Its location is:

```
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\Metabase.xml
```

inside the XML file find the sections jeff talks about, and make those changes.

beware of one detail, default IIS 6 compression settings introduces problems for users behind some proxies, some HTTP 1.0 related issue ( http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=501192 ), so make sure to disable the compression for HTTP 1.0 requests by setting the following setting to true:

```
HcNoCompressionForHttp10="TRUE"
```

details at: https://serverfault.com/questions/12398/http-compression-in-iis-6-0-causing-problems-with-certain-users

Comment: Great answer. The path to the xml in particular what I was after (don't like not knowing where the options are). I checked the other option you mentioned and it's already true, I guess that's default :)

Comment: lucky you, i've been pulling my hair for two months because of that :) . althouth, i don't remember if it was false by default, or by copying jeff's configuration from blog post...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great walk-through on enabling HTTP Compression (gzip) on IIS 6:
http://engineering.leads360.com/post/9301650692/http-compression-gzip-on-iis-6

Answer (score 0):

You do it in IIS Manager.

[Microsoft Docs on IIS 6 HTTP Compression](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/502ef631-3695-4616-b268-cbe7cf1351ce.mspx?mfr=true)